# how to parse passed paramaters with libfcgi

Tags: c, parsing, query-string, fastcgi

I am studying all the examples provided with fcgi-2.4.0 . I want to parse the variables passed with either GET or POST to my fast cgi application, but I am not able to find any example.

Does fcgi provide method for parsing the passed parameter or shall I parse by hand QUERY_STRING? And what about posted files to the cgi?